# Can't write char array to Windows Registry key

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I am trying to write to the Windows Registry using the Win32 API, but for some reason when I try writing bytes to a Registry key with the `REG_BINARY` data type, the key value does not change.

Here is code that attempts to write to the Registry key:

```cpp
struct angles
{
    float pitch;
    float yaw;
    float roll;
};
    
int main()
{
    angles ang;
    ang.pitch = 69.25;
    ang.yaw = 420.21;
    ang.roll = 100.0;
    unsigned char b[sizeof(ang)];
    
    std::cout << "Size of structure: " << sizeof(ang) << "\n\n";
    
    memcpy(b, &ang, sizeof(ang));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(b); i++)
    {
        printf("Byte %d == %02X ", i, b[i]);
        std::cout << "\n\n";
    }
    
    HKEY handle;
    if (RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, KEY_WRITE, &handle) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        if (RegSetValueEx(handle, L"test", 0, REG_BINARY, (BYTE*)&b, sizeof(b)) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            std::cout << "Wrote to key test.\n\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Couldnt write key\n";
        }
    }
    else
        std::cout << "couldn't open key\n";
    
    while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD0))
    {
    
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

If you compile the code, you'll see that I am copying the bytes of the angles struct into the char array `b`.

When calling `RegOpenKeyEx()`, it succeeds.  And when calling `RegSetValueEx()`, it succeeds.  But, the value in the Registry does not change.

So, I'm not sure what to do at this point. I am running the application as admin as well.

Comment: Are you running a 32-bit program? Your key might be in the 32-bit registry

Comment: oh god lol , I spent 2 hours debugging in x86 you were right x64 compiled works. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes, the Registry can hold binary data. That is what the `REG_BINARY` value type is meant for.

Comment: @Ballers On a side note, if you use the ANSI function `RegOpenKeyExA()`, you should use the ANSI function `RegSetValueExA()` to match. More importantly, you are not calling `RegCloseKey()` if `RegOpenKeyExA()` succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Alan Birtles

I had to compile in x64 mode instead of x86.

Comment: In your `RegOpenKeyEx()` call, change it from `KEY_WRITE` TO `KEY_WRITE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY` then you can use it in either 32bit or 64bit compilation

Comment: Or `KEY_WOW64_32KEY`, as needed. See [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys) and [Accessing an Alternate Registry View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/accessing-an-alternate-registry-view).

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: I'm not sure how. I dont see a "Best answer" option for his comment.

Comment: @Ballers You can refer to [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)